# NSMutableArray is not maintaining data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have created a custom class for EmployeeInfo:

```
@interface METEmployee : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *EmpNo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *FirstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *MiddleName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *LastName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *Department;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *HireDate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *JobTitle;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *SupervisorNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *SupLastName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *SupFirstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *MobilePhone;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *EmailAddress;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *DeskPhone;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *EmployeeType;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *Location;
@end
```

Then in my view controller.h I have created:

```
NSMutableArray *theemplyees;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *theemplyees;
```

Synthesize is .m:

```
@synthesize theemplyees
```

Then in ViewDidLoad, init and call to populate it:

```
theemplyees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self getEmps];
```

In getEmps, I add the records to the array:

```
        results = [database executeQuery:@"select * from EmpInfo order by LastName"];
    while([results next]) {

        METEmployee *empInfo = [METEmployee alloc];
        empInfo.EmpNo = [results stringForColumn:@"EmpNo"];
        empInfo.FirstName = [results stringForColumn:@"FirstName"];
        empInfo.MiddleName = [results stringForColumn:@"MiddleName"];
        empInfo.LastName = [results stringForColumn:@"LastName"];
        empInfo.Department = [results stringForColumn:@"Department"];
        empInfo.HireDate = [results stringForColumn:@"HireDate"];
        empInfo.JobTitle = [results stringForColumn:@"JobTitle"];
        empInfo.SupervisorNumber = [results stringForColumn:@"SupervisorNumber"];
        empInfo.SupFirstName = [results stringForColumn:@"SupFirstName"];
        empInfo.SupLastName = [results stringForColumn:@"SupLastName"];
        empInfo.MobilePhone = [results stringForColumn:@"MobilePhone"];
        empInfo.EmailAddress = [results stringForColumn:@"EmailAddress"];
        empInfo.DeskPhone = [results stringForColumn:@"DeskPhone"];
        empInfo.EmployeeType = [results stringForColumn:@"EmployeeType"];
        empInfo.Location = [results stringForColumn:@"Location"];
        [theemplyees addObject:empInfo];
    }
```

Everything works fine for populating the table for the the first screen full of records:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  METEmpTableViewCell *cell = (METEmpTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

cell.lblFirstName.text = [[theemplyees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
cell.lblLastName.text = [[theemplyees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"LastName"];
cell.lblDepartment.text = [[theemplyees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Department"];

 NSString* picName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [[theemplyees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"EmpNo"]];
@try {
    cell.empPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:picName];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

}
@finally { 
}

return cell;
```

}

But if I attempt to scroll up or down on the Tableview, the array says the data is null...although it still shows the record count.  If I resize my cell pn the table to smaller, it will populate more rows (that are visible) but once again any scrolling and they are gone.

Any thoughts or sugguestions is greatly appreciated.   Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Geo...

Comment: Besides the fact that all your properties are weak for no clear reason, you're forgetting to init after you alloc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the mark down Chuck.  Makes me want to ask more questions.

Comment: Wow. I have never seen somebody respond so poorly to being given good advice before. Are you under the impression that I benefit from you asking more questions? Because, really, you came here for advice, and I gave it — just because it seemed like a helpful thing to do, not because I'm desperately hoping you'll ask more questions in the future.

Comment: To be clear, there was nothing at all sarcastic about any of my comments. It really is a mistake to alloc without initing, and I really did find your sarcastic reply to my advice pretty surprising.

Comment: Your right, I apologize.  Been working on a deadline and a bit stressed.  Still no excuse to take it out on you especially since you were offering help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You all have weak properties which means that all of the strings are instantly deallocated, since nothing is retaining them.  Change it to this and try:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theString;
```

Also, you want to initialize your NSMutableArray like so (you're missing the init method):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Wow...if only all answers were that easy!  That did it.  Can't believe I didn't catch that.  Thanks so much.  Been racking my head over this for hours.

Comment: He probably ought to init the METEmployee object too.